# custom font with UITextFields

Tags: ios

I am trying to add a custom font to a UITextView. I am able to use custom fonts with my UILabels, but it is not working with UITextViews. I also tried to use the following code to get it to work, but no success...

```
UIFont *Digital = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7" size:15];

            AboutText.font = Digital;
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you tried creating a property for the font?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
[yourTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital" size:15]]
```

Just make sure that if the font you want to use is actually in XCode as a listed font, and it sounds like you do (if you're already using it for your labels).

Comment: Well, it's not a listed font. It's a custom font. I am using it with my Labels without any problems though, after creating a separate UILabel font class. I tried the same with a UITextView class, but it was not working. I tried your solution, but that did not do the trick...

Comment: I would try to import your custom font into XCode, steps given [here](http://www.daveallanson.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56:adding-custom-fonts-ios-4&catid=38:blog&Itemid=56), and then using the above, you should be able to call the font into your textView. if you follow the tutorial, it should work, it does for me.